# Apparently I'm not converting all arguments during string formatting but I can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to make a program that has the user input a number and check if it's even or odd by dividing it by 2 and seeing if there's a remainder. but I keep getting an error saying "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

I haven't been able to do much because I can't find anything about it anywhere.

```py
var = input("Enter a number!")
var1 = var % 2
if var1 > 0:
   print("The entered number is odd")
else:
   print("The entered number is even")
```

Comment: `int()` wrap around `input(..)` makes the input read an integer. Also, the condition you need is just `if var1:`.

Comment: Why do you have three quotes before the `print` instead of the expected 4-space indent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python builtin  [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)  function gives you a string, you have to convert it to a int using `int(input(..))`

```
#Converted string to int
var = int(input("Enter a number!"))

var1 = var % 2
if var1 > 0:
    print("The entered number is odd")
else:
    print("The entered number is even")
```

Then the output will look like

```
Enter a number!5
The entered number is odd

Enter a number!4
The entered number is even
```

Note that your code will break if you provide a string as an input here

```
Enter a number!hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/devesingh/Downloads/script.py", line 2, in <module>
    var = int(input("Enter a number!"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'
```

So you can do a `try/except` around conversion, and prompt the user if he doesn't give you an integer

```
var = None

#Try to convert to int, if you cannot, fail gracefully
try:
    var = int(input("Enter a number!"))
except:
    pass

#If we actually got an integer
if var:
    var1 = var % 2
    if var1 > 0:
        print("The entered number is odd")
    else:
        print("The entered number is even")
else:
    print("You did not enter a number")
```

The output will then look like

```
Enter a number!hello
You did not enter a number

Enter a number!4
The entered number is even

Enter a number!5
The entered number is odd
```

Looks much better now doesn't it :)

Comment: With the first option you gave me (without the try/except thing) I still get an error directed at line 3 (var1 = var % 2) saying "not all arguments converted during string formatting" any ideas?

Comment: How many arguments are you passing? You need to pass just one argument like I did in sample output  @ShadowToad

Comment: Got it to work! Just had to make it var1 = int(var % 2_

Answer (score 0):

Like Austin mentioned in his comment, you need to typecast the output of the `input` function.

`input` returns a string, and asking for a remainder of a division between a string and a number is nonsensical.

```
var = int(input("Enter a number!"))
var1 = var % 2
if var1 > 0:
    print("The entered number is odd")
else:
    print("The entered number is even")
```